# What is the best way to retrofit an underfloor heating system in a concrete slab?

Tags: plumbing, central-heating

I have a UK bungalow that I am renovating. I would like to replace the current heating system (radiators, natural gas boiler) with an underfloor heating system. I think the cost of digging up the existing concrete floor for the whole property would be prohibitive.

What other options are there?

Answer (score 2):

If you have sufficient ceiling height, you could consider laying a new floor over the existing floor.

I'm assuming that since the bungalow needs refurbishing, then there is unlikely to be any (or at least sufficient) insulation under the existing slab, so you'd need to insulate under any new underfloor heating - no point having the sub-floor sucking half of the heat out of you new underfloor heating system! Unfortunately, that means that you could easily be looking at 100mm (or more) on top of the existing floor by the time you've accounted for the insulation and screed.

That in turn will give other issues to look at. Doors will become too low. Windows could need to be re-glazed with toughened glass if they then fall within the limit on distance from the floor.

Comment: Thanks for that all sounds reasonable, Ceiling height won't be a problem but the door height would be restrictive

Comment: Trimming the bottom of doors off with a circular saw is pretty simple to do if that helps you decide.  Get a good fine cut blade.  To make sure you're strait on your cuts you can use a pair of clamps and a 2x1 to create a guide.

Comment: It's not so much about trimming the doors down, but more that the top of the door opening would be restrictively low. You could consider lifting the lintels over the door to give a standard door opening height above the new floor level. If you are doing sufficient refurbishment to need Building Regulation approval, you might also need to raise the paving outside to give you a level access.